# Does SSD have a better workload limit than HDD if use it for read only?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hardware-failure, workload-simulation

I recently came into an issue of storage a 5 TB database, where the database is expected to be read rather frequently(with all its data). Thus the workload limit of a HDD came into play.

The standard HDD had a workload limit of 100-500. However, though the SSD had a lower number TBW, the number of data to be written to a SSD, it was claimed that read from the SSD won't cause any damage.

Does that mean that if I use SSD to storage 5TB of data and read it frequently, it would last much longer than HDD?

Comment: "a workload limit of 100-500" - I don't understand this, what do these numbers represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what you mean by "a workload limit of 100-500", but ignoring that - in theory yes.  It will also be a lot faster to use an SSD then an HDD.   Just be aware that HDD's are more likely to give warnings of failure, and partially fail, while SSD's are more likely to fail suddenly and catastrophically - so you should still use RAID and consider replication.

That said, while no doubt the write load will be less on a heavy read database, don't be lulled into believing that *no* writes will occur when reading.  (Things like indexes, logs swap will likely still be present)

Comment: Thinking more about your use case, I wonder how practical it would be to RAID an SSD and HDD (in a RAID1 type configuration), and ensuring your RAID solution can use "write mostly" for the HDD.  In this way reads should come mainly from the SSD but you have the reliability of RAID in case the SSD fails.  (see https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Write-mostly for a discussion on this in Linux software RAID)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the SSD will last longer for a couple reasons:

1. SSDs don't incur an endurance penalty from reads like HDDs do, so if we assume your workload is around 75/25 (75% reads, 25% writes), the SSD will be burning through its endurance 1/4 as fast as the HDD.
2. SSDs don't have moving parts and therefore have a much lower AFR (Annualized Failure Rate), meaning they can be run harder for longer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "SSDs don't incur an endurance penalty from reads" - Not 100% accurate but perhaps close enough.